# inline assembly in c++ using visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, assembly

I  tried to compile the following code using visual studio 2010 under 64 bit windows 7.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int strlen2(char str[] )
{
int x ;
    _asm
        {   
            MOV ESI,0;
    LA:     MOV DL,BYTE PTR str[ESI];
            CMP DL,0;
            JE EXIT;
            INC ESI;
            JMP LA;
    EXIT:   MOV x,ESI;

        };

return x;
}

int main()
{
char X[] ="string2222";
cout<<strlen2(X);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and I expect that the output will be "10Press any key to continue . . .",
       but unfortunately, the output was
"3Press any key to continue . . ." for any value of X[].
could you please explain where is the error???

Comment: I love the irony of an inline assembly version of `strlen` with [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) (H-bomb to kill an ant) in the same program. (Also, why is this tagged `C` if the program is `C++`?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz (Veering off topic here, but I suppose the question is tagged both C and C++ because the issue in question is equally valid in both, and this tagging might attract a larger, but still relevant, audience. I'm thinking this is fair game. Isn't it? :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff: It's dangerous, because if the problem actually is language specific, it can cause chaos. But in this case, there's unlikely to be any harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're measuring the length of your pointer (which fortunately has zero in the top byte), rather than the string.

Try this instead:

```
        MOV ESI,0;
        MOV EBX, strl
LA:     MOV DL,[ESI + EBX];
        CMP DL,0;
        JE EXIT;
        INC ESI;
        JMP LA;
EXIT:   MOV x,ESI;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an environment to test this, but I suspect you need another level of indirection when accessing `str` in

```
LA:     MOV DL,BYTE PTR str[ESI];
```

You are probably scanning the value of the pointer rather than the pointed-to string.